# Firebase unlink doesn't completely unlink the Facebook provider

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm only using a phone number as method of login; Now I added Facebook to link to the account, and I noticed that besides the facebook icon being added to the Providers column on the Firebase Authentication section, the corresponding email to that facebook account is also added on the Identifier column.

The problem is, when I unlink Facebook from the account, its email stays in the Identifier column. Only the facebook icon is being removed from the Providers column. See screenshot below:

[image]

This is an issue because now I cannot use other devices to link that facebook account even though I unlinked it already.

Answer (score 0):

When you link multiple providers to a users, you end up with a single top-level user profile, and then separate data for each provider under it.

The email address you see there as the identifier is the email address associated with the top-level user profile.

When you unlink the accounts, the provider data is removed, but the top-level user profile is unmodified, since it is at this unknown where the email address came from.